# Vue 2 - promise not resolving after routing to different page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

I know this question may sound repetitive, but I've been searching for a solution for a long time, and couldn't find any.

I have a `method` that resolves a `promise` after the window is loaded. Later, I am waiting for that method in my `mounted` hook. When routing to that page, neither the promise itself, nor anything after it is executed. However, if I refresh the page, everything runs smoothly.

As an example, this is my `method`:

```
getPosition() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            console.log("window is loaded");
            resolve();
        });
    });
},
```

This is my `mounted` hook:

```
async mounted() {
    console.log("before promise");  // this logs
    await this.getPosition();       // this does not log
    console.log("after promise");   // this does not log
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`getPosition` is not guaranteed to be executed before `load`, and race condition will result in pending promise. That a window has already been loaded should be additionally checked:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      resolve();
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", () => resolve());
});
```

`load` event happens after loading all images and styles, which is not usually needed but results in additional delay. Most times it's useful to wait for DOM instead:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
      resolve();
      return;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => resolve());
});
```

*`load` and `DOMContentLoaded` event are expected to be emitted once on initial page load. Subsequent DOM changes and network requests aren't supposed to be tracked through them.*

Comment: I'm not sure race condition is the case here. One, I don't actually want `getPosition()` to be executed before `load`. I want it to run when window is loaded. And second, weirdly enough, all of these works perfectly as needed if I just refresh the page when already routed on it. It does not work exactly when I route to it. And also, I actually need `load` specifically. I need to wait for an image to load.

Comment: But you already executed getPosition after load, this is the reason why this problem occurs. By race condition I meant that load event has been already emitted. It's emitted once on page load. If you want to track image load events after it then you likely have XY problem, it's not supposed to be solved from this side.

Comment: So you mean that `load` event might happen before my call to `getPosition()`? Then why the logic works fine if I'm just refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes. I didn't say this explicitly it in the answer because this is presumed for the event, that's how the lifecycle works. It worked because the page hasn't loaded (stabilized) yet at the time when the app is mounted and initial router navigation is performed. `load`, etc were heavily used in times of jQuery and server-only routing, they aren't really useful in SPA for anything but global things like loading third-party script (analytics, etc) once at the appropriate time.

Comment: Don't know why, but could not make it work. Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: What exactly did not work and what did you try?

Comment: I tried to add additional check for 'readyState' like you showed, but it's behaving chaotically between routing and refreshing. I don't even know how to describe it. Then, I thought to move the 'load' event listener in 'created' hook, so that it would actually wait for loading. That did not work either. So at the end I just went a different way to achieve the final result.

Comment: Yes, as said, it won't work for what you're trying it to use, i.e tracking image loading state at any moment, you chose a wrong way to do this. You can only make it not block a route when a moment is inappropriate, that's what the post shows.

Comment: I see. Anyways, I just went more simply, and called every next method at the end of previous. Btw, didn't know Vue had `@load` directive argument.