# setTimeout not working on vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, settimeout

I have a function that starts up after 1 second from page loading, during the development phase locally it works, but when I build my application and put it on a server the timeout no longer works (on chrome it works only after accepting the banner of cookies and reloaded the page), while if I go in incognito mode it does not work.

This is the code of timeout:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {       
this.brake();     
},1000);
```

This is a vue.js application.

I tried to modify the function by inserting this piece of code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.brake();
    },1000);
}, false);
```

but it still doesn't work.

The link of the test site is: https://new.carbobrake.com/

Once the page has finished loading the disk should stop by itself, but this does not happen.

----EDIT----

This is my code:

```
<div id="animation-container">
      <img id="fixed-canvas-container" :src="this.homeImages[0]" alt="" />
      <img id="scroll-canvas-container" :src="this.animationImages[0]" alt="" />
      
      
      <div id="step0">
      // other code
      </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
methods: {
  brake() {
        this.canvasContainer = document.getElementById("fixed-canvas-container");
        this.canvasContainer.src = this.homeImages[1];
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.body.style.overflowY = "visible";
          this.setImageMargin();
          document.getElementById("scroll-canvas-container").style.display =
            "block";

          var step0 = document.getElementById("step0");

          TweenMax.fromTo(
            step0,
            0.5,
            {
              display: "none",
              opacity: 0,
            },
            {
              display: "block",
              opacity: 1,
              ease: Power3.easeIn,
            }
          );
        }, 1100);
        // TODO check
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.canvasContainer.style.display = "none";
        },2500);

   }
 }, 
  mounted() {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.brake();
      }, 1000);
  
  }
```

Comment: See the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608013/3731501 . You don't really need DOMContentLoaded in Vue apps and shouldn't rely on random timeouts in general. It's unknown how this code is used, which is important here.

Comment: I tried to insert a test condition as you wrote, but it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The problem with race conditions that occurs in unknown conditions can't be solved

Comment: I added some code

Comment: This requires the whole thing to be untangled. It's not shown where animationImages and homeImages come from. There should be strict conditions when they are available, preferably with promise control flow. instead of random timeouts.

Comment: `mounted() { this.$nextTick(this.brake) }` [nexttick docs](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) and change the `document.getElementById`'s to [refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html). classic vue beginner problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', this.brake);
```

Now it works correctly at the end of the page load.